# Get filesystem name and usage with `df -h`

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, awk, df

```
 df -h | grep test | sed -e 's/*%.^ //g;s/.*[ ^I]//'
```

Output:

```
/test
/test/drv0
/test/drv1
```

```
 df -h  | grep test  | cut -d '%' -f1 | sed -e 's/*%.^ //g;s/.*[ ^I]//'
```

Output:

```
10
20
15
```

I want to know how can I join those outputs like this:

```
/test 10
/test/drv0 20
/test/drv1 15
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
df -P | sed -n '/test/s/.*[[:blank:]]\(.*\)%[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)/\2 \1/p'
```

(that assumes the mount point paths don't contain % or newline characters)

Comment: +1 for `-P` (posix) usage.

Answer (score 8):

I think something as follow. I don't understand the whole question though

```
df -h | awk '/test/{print $1" "$5}' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' -e 's/%//g'
```

Since the question has changed, here is the updated answer

```
df -h | awk '/test/{print $1, +$5}'
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean about +$5. Do you mean the awk part?. Can you provide an example. Feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: @asonwryan  This will trim the space between test/ and the percentage. So I don't think that's what the questioner want.

Comment: My bad: forgot to add space. Fixed.

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice one! Eliminates the need for sed.

Answer (score 6):

```
df | awk '/test/ {print $1 " " $5}'
```

will print

```
/test 10%
/test/drv0 20%
/test/drv1 15%
```

Comment: Many ways to remove the percent sign, including `| tr -d '%'`

Comment: That assumes mount point paths don't contain blank characters.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas yes, it does. But I'd argue that that's pretty uncommon and not in the scope of such a simple shell solution.

Comment: @glennjackman I know, but I intentionally left that part as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 4):

This is not a good solution for your particular situation (it works, but is needlessly complex), you should use the answers already provided. I just wanted to mention another tool that is very useful when you want to join the output of multiple programs, `paste`:

```
DESCRIPTION
   Write  lines  consisting  of  the sequentially corresponding lines from
   each FILE, separated by TABs, to standard output.   With  no  FILE,  or
   when FILE is -, read standard input.
```

Combined with bash [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), you can combine the output of your two commands like this:

```
$ paste  <(df -h | grep test | sed -e 's/*%.^ //g;s/.*[ ^I]//') \
       <(df -h  | grep test  | cut -d '%' -f1 | sed -e 's/*%.^ //g;s/.*[ ^I]//')
 /test 10
 /test/drv0 20
 /test/drv1 15
```

Or, to use a simpler example:

```
$ paste <(echo -e "a\nb\nc") <(echo -e "1\n2\n3")
a   1
b   2
c   3
```

Comment: I have never seen (or thought of) having multiple input redirections in a case like this.  No idea it would have even worked.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `int()` function in awk that will remove `%` and important is `-P` flag to `df` because if partition in LVM then also it's print properly.

```
df -hP | awk '/test/{print $1,int($5)}'
```